# Unable to get this function working in .vimrc

Tags: vim, cygwin

Not sure if this is the best place for this question but following this http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_the_Windows_clipboard_in_Cygwin_Vim article I put this function ***Putclip*** in my vimrc however it doesnt seem to get triggered.

```
vnoremap <silent> <leader>y :call Putclip(visualmode(), 1)<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <leader>y :call Putclip('n', 1)<CR>
```

I thought the above two calls to the function should work in vm mode or normal mode when pressing **y** command. Even the highlight on mouse in vm mode doesnt work. Can someone please let me know what im doing wrong.

I use cygwin as the environment to do this and using vim version 7.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These map the command not to `y`, but to `<leader>y`. By default, the leader key is a backslash, so the command is really bound to `\y`. You can change that by setting the `mapleader` variable to something else before mapping a command to a key sequence incorporating it:

```
let mapleader = ","
vnoremap <silent> <leader>y :call Putclip(visualmode(), 1)<CR>
```

Now the function would be bound to `,y` instead of `\y`.

Comment: You have error: `mapleader` must be written without a space. You should also mention that this `:let` statement must go before `<Leader>` mapping in question to have effect. And since when `<CR>` became unnecessary to run an ex-mode command?

Comment: Autocorrect inserted the space; I'll fix. Good point about setting the value. And I ignored a level of indirection regarding my comment on `<CR>`.